# Iframe firefox issue

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, iframe, slider, opera

the following page
http://uliinternational.com/ 
has a slider that is loaded through an iframe
it displays perfectly in opera and chrome(both latest) but seems to move to the right in firefox (4)
i cant seem to figure it out
the code used to insert the iframe is really simple

```
<iframe src="http://uliinternational.com/slider/index.htm" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

i am aware that its overlapping the searchbox( intend to fix that later) and i hope its not relevant here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you apply the style `display:block` to the iframe.